# Copying array contents to cell in vectorised way MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, cell-array

I have a nx3 array `A`. I want to create a cell `B` such that:

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
    B{i}=A(i,:);
end
```

Can i do this in a vectorised way without for loop or any faster than this in Matlab?

**EDIT:**

This question arose to me because i wanted to call a function on each row of `A`. The function outputs a scalar only. So once i have formed `B`, i can call `cellfun`:

```
C=cellfun(@func,B)
```

I did this. `for` loop still seems better.

```
b=rand(1000000,15);
tic
for i=1:size(b,1)
    f{i}=b(i,:);
end
toc

tic
e=mat2cell(b, ones([1 size(b,1)]), [ size(b,2) ]);
toc

OUTPUT:
Elapsed time is 1.386777 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.237526 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mat2cell` to have a cell matrix `B`, then you can call the rows of `B` into `cellfun`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function [`mat2cell`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
B=mat2cell(A, ones(1, size(A,1)), size(A,2));
```